# Is it possible to have ApplicationContext use Validators when creating beans?

Tags: java, spring, validation

In Spring 3.0, `ApplicationContext` performs miscellaneous verification when creating beans and performing dependency injections.

It is possible to have it use a bean `validator` or should I have it call back a `@PostConstruct` method calling this validator?

**Update**

This validator would perform deeper validation than `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to validate? Depending on your needs [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) might fit.